# How to set read file permission for "mac" similiar to right click for PC

Tags: php, mysql, permissions

I'm working locally on a mac and trying to set the permissions for myself. I found a tutorial for right-click on the folder and choose "Properties" BUT this is for PC including a tutorial. Its very easy and you can see from this link (It if for PC)
http://www.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson16.php

**BUT what about mac?** I've searched but what I've found is complicated permission. **Why can't it simple as right click for PC but not for mac**. I'd appreciate an easier way.

I've one folder called TEXT and I only want to allow READ only permission.

I've a php is already written but I can't see anything on MAMP as local host? I'm using mac.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php
 $file=fopen("text/readonly.txt","r"); or exit("Unable to open file!"); 
 //Output a line of the file until the end is reached
 while(!feof($file)) // end of file
   {
   echo fgets($file). "<br />";
   }
 fclose($file);
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`chmod`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).

Comment: For PC its a right click, easy. For mac? How? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Select the object in Finder and hit `CMD+I`. A window will pop up showing the file permissions at the bottom. See here:

[image: File Info]

Of course it doesn't look like on a PC. It's a Mac anyway :) if you click the lock on the lower right of the window, you can unlock the table above it and modify the rights according to your needs after you entered the admin password. with the `+` you can add additional user, with the small arrows next to `Lesen & Schreiben` (Read & Write) you can change the associated access rights for that user (eg to `Lesen` (Read only).

Comment: I've tried it doen't work, I've compare it to a tutorial http://www.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson16.php and it is not a same thing?

Comment: Thank you DocJones. I did that. It look like it is not CMD+I and it now appear to be something else? Are you familiar with PHP read only 'r'? Something that can be forced?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.4/en/mh669.html) is the official explanation from apple. [There](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-file-permissions.html) is a explanation with more pictures.

Comment: Thank you Doc Jones and I appreciate it.